# Sine wave on the environment texture

Tags: node-editor, skybox

I am trying to create a Sine wave that goes around the environment texture (something like what is shown in the attached image)

[image]
I have tried to mess up around with the math nodes.

So far I am trying to mess up a bit with the math nodes and I have made this:

[image]
Which gives this as a result:
[image]

This makes sense, but I cannot figure out a way on how could I do what I want.
How could I create and deal with this kind of issue?

btw: I am quite familiar with trigonometry and mathematical functions as my background is engineering.

Answer (score 6):

That can be this kind of settings:

[image]

**Base nodes** (with X and Y centered from *"generated"* coordinates, using *"vector mapping"*)

- Take the angle through *"separate X Y Z"* and *"artan2"* using X and Y.
- Get the *"sin"*.
- And compare it to Z value.

**Tuning (in green above)**

- Multiply the angle with some value to have the wave amount.
- Multiply Z to handle the wave height.
- Use some value to tune the wave line height.

[image]

here a blend file for 2.8:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'll take Lemon's excellent answer and modify it to use Blender's built in textures for those of us who don't work so well with math nodes.

We can run a large wave texture through a color ramp to squeeze down and isolate a solid line on the z axis.  (Rough equivalent to running z channel through compare node)

[image]

We can create a second wave texture using a radial gradient as the vector to define a period for our sine wave.  (Radial gradient outputs the arctan2 operation mapped from -pi to pi.)

[image]

Then we can mix this period mask into our z coordinate, and basically we're telling blender to pull down the z coordinates in the white spaces, and controlling how much with the mix factor.

[image]

[image]

Finally, if you want to recreate the "drawn" feeling of the reference, you can mix noise into the main texture coordinate.

[image]