# How can I create a wire-wove grid material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, procedural

I'm trying to create a procedural cycles material which looks like a speaker of a mobile phone.

My attempt is by mixing two Wave Textures and rotating them by 45°. Any hints on how I can make it look more link my [reference image](https://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/themes/ap2/ap_resize/ap_resize.php?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpolice.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F10%2FPixel-3-XL-top-speaker-hero.jpg&w=728)?

[image: Blender grid material setup]

**Update**

I used Blender 2.80 but the answer uses a newer one. I updated Blender to 2.93 in order to have the same settings on the nodes used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not super happy with this one, but when it comes down to it you might have to fiddle around with just about any solution that's given to you.  It's kind of the nature of procedural generation, so here goes.

This is based on another answer I did over here:
[Sine wave on the environment texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203631/sine-wave-on-the-environment-texture/203643#203643)

You can read through that for the whole discussion on this.  *Here* we do a Y Wave Texture influencing an X Wave Texture, and then reverse it to get a 90 degree rotation.  Then we add those two together and use it for the Alpha channel.

[image: default plane, generated coordinates]

For this primitive plane, the scales should always be around the same (but they don't have to be *exactly* the same) and the Mix Factor controls the height of the wave.  So it should always be *very close* to 1, but how close depends on the scale of the wave textures.  You'll have to mess with them to get it to look right depending on the size of the mesh it's applied to.

Comment: Excellent answer. Could you elaborate a bit on what the ColorRamp does in this setup? I read the other answer you linked but I'm confused what it means.

Comment: @BrunoBieri the color ramps take the wave texture output, which is normally a gradient, and makes it a hard cutoff and shrinks down the white portion